# Oracle DBMS_ALERT Waitany Delay

Tags: oracle, asynchronous, plsql, jobs

I have a job, which will submit n other jobs.  I have setup my pl/sql procedure to register for the n jobs using dbms_alert.register.  Each of these jobs will send a dbms_alert.signal.  I have issued a commit immediatly after the signal.

Here is the problem, when my program gets to the dbms_alert.waitany, not signal will be returned for 5 seconds (almost excactly every time).  The procedure will submit another n jobs, and once again waitany will not recieve any signals for about 5 seconds.

I have done my research and have seen that the default polling interval for dbms_alert.waitany is 5 seconds.  This can be changed by using the dbms_alert.set_defaults procedure.  I have done that with no effect.  I have littered my code with dbms_alert.set_defaults(1) (also tried 600 as well), trying to get the signals less than 5 seconds, but nothing works.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You should just need to call `set_defaults` just prior to your call to `waitany`, I think. The documentation and other sources online are quite unclear about this procedure - whether the "sensitivity" parameter is in seconds or hsecs is not clear.

Comment: Also seen: "The WAITANY call uses a polling loop to detect alerts. ... The polling loop begins with a 1-second interval that increases exponentially to 30 seconds." - no mention of set_defaults.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the deprecated initialization parameter _job_queue_interval. It can still be set with

`alter system set "_job_queue_interval"=5 scope=spfile;`

...and restarting the database.

The DBMS_ALERT.SET_DEFAULTS procedure sets the polling interval **in case a polling loop is required** (which is very rare). Refer to the [Oracle 10g docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_alert.htm) about when polling occurs (which is very rare).